# Python dateutil.rrule skip every nth occurrence

Tags: python-3.x, python-dateutil

It's easy to get the nth occurrence of a `dateutil.rrule.rrule` instance:

```
rule = dateutil.rrule.rrule(...)
occurrence = rule[15]
```

...But I have an occurrence such that `occurrence in rule is True`; I would like to know which occurrence it is (i.e. the index of the occurrence, which is 15 in the above example) without causing performance problems, as I may need to do this with a lot of occurrences.

Is this possible, and if so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a method that would allow you to run a test on values with the current set of functions.

However, depending of how frequently you perform your calculations, you might consider doing the followings:

1. Use the [`cache` feature](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html):

> cache – If given, it must be a boolean value specifying to enable or
>   disable caching of results. If you will use the same rrule instance
>   multiple times, enabling caching will improve the performance
>   considerably.

2. Remap your results onto a numpy array for optimum index resolution:

Given `r` being a large set of results:

```
>>> r # Your result set
<dateutil.rrule.rrule object at 0x7f616d4182e8>
>>> r[1] # Example of what's inside
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> import numpy as np # Let's load numpy
>>> a = np.array(list(r)) # We build a numpy array, should be fast
>>> np.argwhere(a == datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)) # Catch'em all!
array([[1]])
```

I am unsure if `np.argwhere()` will be faster than iterating over the result set with a simple loop, but this is a more readable approach.